# execute an action from a javafx menu item and keeping gui and action in separate files

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, menuitem

Who: I work for the County ambulance service. We have forty ambulances and about two hundred fire apparatus.

What:   I am asking your help to write a compute program in Java. I have a GUI that I constructed in JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0. I am using Netbeans to code up the application. Enclosed is some very simple code for the GUI. My question is in two parts; 
Question 1.) I have an Analysis menu with a Expected Call Volume menu item. I also have the code that reaches into my database and pulls out this information and generates a Poisson frequency distribution. How do I marry those two things together. In other words, when a user clicks the menu item it should fire off the code. How do I attach the code to this menu item?
Question 2.) Perhaps not a question, I am keeping the action code in a separate .java file. The reason I am doing this is to keep separate the gui from the code. I think it will be more manageable to have pieces that do unique things. Is there anything special I need to do to tie this separate java file into the GUI? Which java file does this action event go to (FXMLDocumentExplorer.java or JavaFXApplication2.java)?

When: hoping to get this accomplished this before 9 October 2015

Where:  JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 and Netbeans 8.02 on a Windows machine. It is JDK 8.

Why:    I have a lot of database code built for understanding ambulance deployment. I would like to package it all up in a software package.

```
   /*When the user clicks the menu item Expected Call Volume this code fires off*/
import java.lang.Math;

public class PoissonExperiment1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
/*This is just an example of code. Keeping it easy. The actual Poisson calculations and JDBC are 200 lines of ugly code.*/
        double c = 7.0;
        int k = 1;
        while (k <= 15)
        {
            int factorialResult = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
            {
                factorialResult = factorialResult * i;
            }
            double term1 = (Math.pow(Math.E, -c));
            double term2 = Math.pow(c, k);
            double numerator = term1 * term2;
            double answer = numerator / factorialResult;
            System.out.format("%10.3f:%n ", answer);
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Netbeans generates the following code (FXMLDocumentController)

```
package javafxapplication2;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

  @FXML
  private Label label;

  @FXML
  private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
  {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    label.setText("Hello World!");
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
  {
  }
}
```

Netbeans also generates the following code (JavaFXApplication2)

```
package javafxapplication2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication2 extends Application
{

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
  {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

JavaFX Scene Builder generates a gui xml document. It doesn't copy and paste well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="247.0" prefWidth="419.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication2.FXMLDocumentController">
  <children>
    <HBox alignment="CENTER" fillHeight="false" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="50.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onMouseClicked="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="192.0" prefWidth="411.0" style="-fx-background-color: FloralWhite;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
      <padding>
        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
      </padding>
    </HBox>
    <Pane layoutX="7.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="247.0" prefWidth="419.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <children>
        <MenuBar layoutX="14.0" layoutY="10.0">
          <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
              </items>
            </Menu>

            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Analysis">
              <items>
                <MenuItem fx:id="mnuCompareTimeFrames" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Expected Call Volume" />
                <MenuItem fx:id="mnuCOPCNCompliance" mnemonicParsing="false" text="COPCN Compliance" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="mnuResponseTimes" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Response Times" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
          </menus>
        </MenuBar>
      </children>
    </Pane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

So how do I put these pieces together? Once I figure out how to fire off some code after the user clicks on a menu item, I can then start to build the rest of this program.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the reactfx project; it provides a relatively painless way to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To marry a menu and a function that does stuff.

Add code like this to the controller class:

```
@FXML
private void handleMenuAction(ActionEvent event) {
    // do stuff if menu is clicked
}
```

You should use a unique name you can recognize even if you have a lot of actions rather than `handleMenuAction`.

Compile.

Double click on the .fxml file in Netbeans which should open Scene Builder.

Select the menu item you want users to click to do something.

On the right side expand the `Code` tab and use the drop-down combo box on the `On Action` field and select the function you just added. If you have many actions you could just type or paste the name in.

In Scene Builder save the .fxml file.

In Netbeans, select the .fxml file in the project tab and right click to select Make Controller (  to make sure the .java file is up to date with .fxml file)

The code you put into that function should be called when the user clicks the menu item.

For question 2, this code needs to be in the Controller class but it could easily be just one line of code that calls a method in any other class.

Comment: Thank you very much WillShackleford. I was able to get this to work. Now I have one question and one clarification. The question is; In the Scene Builder I click on the menu item I wish to add functionality to. On the right side I expand the code tabe and use the drop-down box for the On Action field. But what if I have many On Action methods. My confusion is that they are all called the same thing (private void handleMenuAction(ActionEvent event)). Or can you provide a unique name for this action event.

Comment: My clarification is when you choose Source within Netbeans and Make Controller - that pertains to the .FXML file. It does not pertain any of the .java files in the project. Once again, thank you very much for your answer. I got it to work.

Comment: You can and probably should use a more unique name in place of handleMenuAction. If the list is really long it may be easier to paste the name in than search the list.